# New google Oauth2

Tags: omniauth, google-oauth

I have the following information I am confused coz of the new format, can anyone tell which of this is app_id and awhich is app secret. Also for the existing app, I am unable to change redirect URI, was not able to find edit information, there is just edit referer button available for the old app so had to make a new app.

```
Client ID:  
9380410xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address:  
938041087404@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret:  
xxxxxx-xxxxxx
Redirect URIs:  xxxx
JavaScript origins:     xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this question is related to the API Console. If so, you can switch back to the old format at https://code.google.com/apis/console